# How can I run fast Draper decorator specs by not loading Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, draper

I want to run draper decorator specs that do not load Rails, if possible, to stick to fast specs.  I'm having a brain fart getting the 2nd line to work.  What am I missing?

```
require "rspec/mocks/standalone"
require "draper/test/rspec_integration"
require_relative "../../app/decorators/articles_decorator"

describe ArticleDecorator do
  describe "#published_date" do
    let(:article)           { double('Article', published_at: Time.now,
                                                content:      'content',
                                                abstract:     'abstract') }
    let(:decorated_article) { ArticleDecorator.new(article) }

    it "returns the article's published_at timestamp in long date form" do
      decorated_article.published_date.should == article.published_at.to_s(:long_date)
    end

    it "returns the article's content when an id is present" do
      decorated_article.abstract_or_content('id').should == 'content'
    end

    it "returns the article's abstract when an id is not present" do
      decorated_article.abstract_or_content.should == 'abstract'
    end
  end
end
```